# Build definition of enterprise products with branch merge policy (pull request)

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been working on a software product since last 2 years. It was all built from scratch. Initially there was only one build definition with one **VSTS GIT** repo. In the beginning build time was just 4-5 mins as it was having few solution files only.

Over the period, build time has increased to an hour because lot of code is added in last 2 years. I enabled gated check-in as well. This means developer has to build everything just a make a small code changes in a small component. I would like to know

1. How to enable gated check-in effectively such that I need not be build entire product. It should only build the changed project only. Assume there is no direct reference of changed project to other projects.
2. I am thinking of breaking the single repo into multiple repo, each repo would have its own build definition. Is this a standard approach to have multiple repos for one product? Can anyone please tell me generally how to build big enterprise products. I am using VSTS build, no jenkins.

Comment: If it's a Git repo, how are you using gated checkin? Are you talking about branch policies?

Comment: You are correct, I mean I have branch merge policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using git, I assume that when you say gated check-in you are using pull requests. More info on pull requests [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests).

For your CI build, you could check what tasks are taking longer and see if you can reduce some of them. Check if you are clean your source files for every build. If so, every time the build starts it has to download you full repository. If that is the case, change that configuration to not clean your sources every time.

Breaking your repo into a multiple repo approach is really a decision you have to make. There is not a good or bad approach on that.

Microsoft it self has different approaches to this in different teams. VSTS team uses one monolitic git repo. Skype team uses multiple repos. Windows teams also use multiple repos.

Multiple repos can reduce your build time and create an isolation level between your software components, but they will bring a more complex way of working for developers, since they have to checkout different repos if they work in more than one. The admins also have to setup more branch policies and so one.